# Function 'PF' not found?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am using JSF 2 and Primefaces 5 and i am trying to show p:dialog when the object "client" is null (not instantiated) like below :

```
<p:commandLink update=":form:connecterPanel" 
   oncomplete="#{empty loginBean.client ? PF('connectDialog').show():''}" title="add to panel">
   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-cart" style="margin:0 auto;" />
</p:commandLink>
```

But i am getting the error **Function 'PF' not found**

Comment: Just a quick thought: `empty` is a bitch in EL-Expressions. I faced similiar issues quite often, the cause are missing brackets. Try `(empty loginBean.c)?`.

Comment: i am still getting the same error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this :

```
oncomplete="if(#{empty loginBean.client }){PF('connectDialog').show()}"
```

Comment: That is weird. Are you 100% sure it is the only thing you changed?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes it was the only thing i have changed, i got the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359606/4663461

Comment: Omfg, didn't see the obvious :-) Yes, ofc. `PF()` is a javascript-method, while el-expressions itself are not aware of javascript-methods. So, in your first code, java searched for a method "PF()", which is wrong. So, what should also work: Inside the EL-Expression, print the function call as "String", which then will be valid Java-Script after html-generation: `oncomplete="#{empty loginBean.client ? \"PF('connectDialog').show()\":''}` (not sure about the escaping) evaluates to `"oncomplete="PF('connectDialog').show()"` or `oncomplete=""` depending on the condition.

Comment: A, i remember: in EL, concatenating strings is a terrible thing with concat, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008504/how-do-i-append-a-quote-to-a-string-in-jsf-el - so your approach is clearly a "good" one, even if the generated html `oncomplete="if(true){PF('connectDialog').show()"` looks strange, if someone checks the source code :-)

Comment: Another approach would be to generate the javascript-string inside a bean-method, and use it like `oncomplete="#{loginBean.onCompleteJavascript}"` with `public string getOnCompleteJavascript(){ if (!this.client.isEmpty()))return "PF('connectDialog').show()"; return "";}`

Comment: @dognose thanks for the link :) i am getting an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44159640/4663461 can you check it please  !!